# What is wrong with this ExpressJS + Passport signup route? It returns 400 Bad Request

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I implemented a signup route below. It gets to "User saved..." but  the request returns 404.

It doesn't seem to be executing the login strategy:

```
router.post("/signup", function(req, res, next) {

    var email = req.body.email;
    var password = req.body.password;

    User.findOne({ email: email },  function(err, user) {

        if (err) { return next(err); }
        if (user) {
            return res.status(409).send({message: "Duplicate user - already registered."});
        }

        var newUser = new User({
            email: email,
            password: password
        });
        newUser.save(next);
        console.log("User saved...");
    });
},
    passport.authenticate("login"),
    function(req, res) {
        return res.status(200).send({
            message: "Signup successful",
            user: req.user
        });
    }
);
```

My Passport login strategy looks like this:

```
    passport.use("login", new LocalStrategy(async (email, password, done) => {
        console.log("login...");
        User.findOne({ email: email }, function(err, user) {
            if (err) { return done(err); }
            if (!user) {
                return done(null, false, { message: "No user has that email!" });
            }
            user.checkPassword(password, function(err, isMatch) {
                console.log("Checked password...");
                console.log("Error? Match?");
                console.log(err);
                console.log(isMatch);
                if (err) { return done(err); }
                if (isMatch) {
                    console.log("Returning done...");
                    return done(null, user, { message: 'Logged in Successfully' });
                } else {
                    return done(null, false, { message: "Invalid password." });
                }
            });
        });
    }));
```

Here's what I see in the logs:

```
User saved...
POST /signup 400 181.122 ms - -
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passport is likely throwing the 400 error because the username/password fields are not set.

Passport expects username and password and what you are passing are the email and password. So you can modify the code and let passport's LocalStrategy use the email as the `username`.

You can set the username and password as follows:

```
passport.use("login", new LocalStrategy({
        usernameField: 'email',
        passwordField: 'password',
    },async (usernameField, passwordField, done) => {
        console.log("login...");
        User.findOne({ email: usernameField }, function (err, user) {
            if (err) { return done(err); }
            if (!user) {
                return done(null, false, { message: "No user has that email!" });
            }
            user.checkPassword(passwordField, function (err, isMatch) {
                console.log("Checked password...");
                console.log("Error? Match?");
                console.log(err);
                console.log(isMatch);
                if (err) { return done(err); }
                if (isMatch) {
                    console.log("Returning done...");
                    return done(null, user, { message: 'Logged in Successfully' });
                } else {
                    return done(null, false, { message: "Invalid password." });
                }
            });
        });
    }));
```

You can check the line which was throwing the error from `passport's` source code [here](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-local/blob/96a4727243588a6f835efefd9e2511c0da1060e6/lib/strategy.js#L75_)

Comment: Yes, you were right, the LocalStrategy constructor was missing the options which specify which fields to use as username, password.